# What is the name of default animation for new activity on android?

Tags: android, resources, scrollview, android-animation

Once user presses button, new activity is shown with animation. 
What is the name of this animation in standard android resources? How can I apply that to my application? (some the animations there (xml files) contains references to other files and to some config values)

Would like to imitate new activity opening, when content of my `ScrollView` is changed.

Comment: Have you heard aboud `ViewFlipper`? I think it's what you need.

Comment: @user639183, can it work with one View only? See no sense to create second one with the same content. And, what will happen if user presses Back button? I want to show previous View (not previous content).

Comment: Actually, I've already added animation. And now just need to understand how this standard animation is named.

Comment: I have no idea about the name of animation. "what will happen if user presses Back button?" You'd have to override it if you'd go with `ViewFlipper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for slide_left_in, slide_left_out, slide_right_in, and slide_right_out.

Answer (score 6):

This helped me it has all the android animations.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.5_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/anim/activity_open_enter.xml?av=f